# How can I use this JQuery plugin to move an object X positions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, templates

http://desandro.com/demo/masonry/docs/

I got this to display nicely.  But,

How can I modify this plugin so that when someone clicks an object, it does the nice "re-ordering" effect as seen in: http://desandro.com/demo/masonry/docs/filtering.html#demo

And it moves the object "X" positions up or down the list?

Is it easy to modify this to do that?

Comment: The re-ordering on that is the shift in element visibility.  Adding an 'order' awareness is something else--you'd have to re-arrange the elements on the DOM via Jquery... Not sure on how though.

Answer (score 0):

From the moment that all elements has `float:left;` when the user click the button hide the element with specific classes, for example if he clicks grey, then will hide red and black. In jquery the above example would be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#grey-button").click(function(){
        $(".red, .black").hide()
    });
});
```

This will hide all elements with classes red and black, adding the css property `display` and value `none`.

This will make the browser don't "see" them, so the rest elements will be positioned in a different place, according the floats you have set for them.

Comment: I don't want to filter. I want to reposition the element.

Comment: maybe a visual example of what you need would help. in the example you give, it filters the elements